# Linked List: error: expected initializer before '<' token

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting the error "error: expected initializer before '<' token" when compiling, I need to create a linked list, and I need to turn one of the functions into a template for an assignment, I was wondering how I can fix the error that I am getting.

```
#ifndef LINK_H
#define LINK_H

class link {
public:
    int data;
    link *lnkPtr;
};


class linked
{
private:    

      link  *head;
public:

        linked(){head = nullptr;}
        ~linked(){};
        void nodeEnd(link *, double num);
        template <class T>
        T nodeBeg<T>(link *, T num);
        void nodeIst(link *, double num);
        void nodeDel(link *, double num);
        link fillLst(int);
        void prntLst(link *);
        void destLst(link *);
        link endLst(link *);
        //void addlink(link *, int);
};

  template <class T>
  T linked<T>::nodeBeg(link* , T num)
{
     link *newNode; // To point to a new node 
     link *nodePtr; // To move through the list 

     // Allocate a new node and store num there. 
     newNode = new link; 
     newNode->data = num; 
     newNode->lnkPtr = nullptr; 

     // If there are no nodes in the list 
     // make newNode the first node.
      if (!head) 
         head = newNode; 
      else // Otherwise, insert newNode at end. 
      { 
         // Initialize nodePtr to head of list. 
         nodePtr = head; 

         // Find the last node in the list. 
         // while (!nodePtr->linkPtr) 
            nodePtr = nodePtr->lnkPtr; 


         nodePtr->lnkPtr = head; //inserts at beginning
      } 
}
#endif /* LINK_H */
```

Comment: class `linked` is not a template. So `linked<T>` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @sam would I be able to make it a template without making all other member functions a template, or would I need to make another class for the function I need to be a template?

Comment: @Ethan_J  no that's two different things

Comment: @Ethan_J Please refer to my answer for your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<T>` from `T nodeBeg<T>(link *, T num);` and `T linked<T>::nodeBeg(link* , T num)` .`T nodeBeg(link *, T num)` and `T linked::nodeBeg(link* , T num)` will tell the compiler to deduce the return type at compile time. Also neither the function `nodeBeg` nor the class `linked` are templates so you don't need the `<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors in your code.
`nodeBeg` is a function template.
It's declaration should be as follows:

```
template <class T> T nodeBeg(link *, T num);
```

The definition should be as follows:

```
template <class T> T linked::nodeBeg(link*, T num) {/*...*/}
```

Here you have to attach `linked::` to the function name, to tell the compiler that you are defining here the member `nodeBeg` of class `linked`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<T>` after identifiers.  Parameter list after an id is a specialization is mean for template specialization.

Template of class and member template are two different things.. member can be a template within template class or it may be not, or class might be a template. if member of template class is template, it got two parameter list.

```
template<typename T1>
struct string {
    // member template function
    template<typename T2>
    int compare(const T2&);
    // constructors can be templates too
    template<typename T2>
    string(const std::basic_string<T2>& s) { /*...*/ }
};
// out of class definition of string<T1>::compare<T2> 
template<typename T1> // for the enclosing class template
template<typename T2> // for the member template
int string<T1>::compare(const T2& s) { /* ... */ }
```

(from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template )